# What does "In this matter acts for and on behalf of" mean?

Tags: meaning

> This agreement is made on _______, by and between:
>
> 1. XXX
>
> **In this matter acts for and on behalf of YYY**.

The above sentence is from an agreement, and XXX and YYY each refers to a name of a person (not sure) and company. For me, the bold sentence seems incomplete. Does this mean:

> The above person XXX acts for and is on behalf YYY in this matter.

Comment: The *first* text you've cited isn't a valid sentence - are you sure it's not just some text next to a dotted line where someone is expected to ***sign*** some agreement (on behalf of XXX)? Without more context, there's not really a question here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have added more context.

Comment: It looks pretty obvious to me that my suggestion above was correct. It's just a "label" telling you who should sign (or telling other people later who ***did*** sign) the agreement. This is hardly "learning English" - it's just "understanding how to complete formal documents". Sorry, I should have said *(on behalf of **YYY**)* in previous comment.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Then does the bold sentence mean "The above person XXX acts for and is on behalf YYY in this matter"? Since this sentence seemed incomplete, it was hard to understand.

Comment: You can't really analyse the "syntax" of a "label" like that. But note that very often the "pre-printed" wording there would be ***acting** for and on behalf of YYY* (a participial clause referring back to the as-yet-unidentified signatory). Whoever drew up the document doesn't know who will sign the document, but they ***do*** know that anyone who does so must be acting on behalf of company YYY. By including that "identifying" clause, they ensure that if anyone who ***isn't*** authorised to act on behalf of the company signs it, the agreement has no validity.

Comment: This looks like a poor translation to me. It should read: Act**ing** in this matter for and on behalf of [some party]. Also, matter may be wrong as contracts are not matters, court cases are. For a contract: "acting for and on behalf of X hereunder"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the grammar a little wrong, but the sense you've inferred is correct.

Person XXX acts *for* YYY (as in, represents them and their interests - like a lawyer acts for their client by representing them in a court of law).

Person XXX also acts *on behalf of* YYY (which means that anything XXX does is to be treated as if YYY did it themselves - for example, if I'm sick and can't sign a document, I can allow you to act on my behalf and sign it with your name, with an understanding that you're signing it for me).

Comment: Very well explained and not in a comment.